# HTTP Status 404 - /WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.html

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Unable to resolve JSP page, whereas it's working fine with a simple string

Here is my folder structure of project 
[image]

I am using following dep. to run an application

### compile('org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:8.0.47')

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class SpringAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
        // Create the 'root' Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(SpringAppConfig.class);

        // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
        container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

        // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        dispatcherContext.register(SpringAppConfig.class);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher",
                new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/");

    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver internalResourceViewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        internalResourceViewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        internalResourceViewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return internalResourceViewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class StudentController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello")    // this is working
    public String sayHello() {
        return "Hello from Spring 5 and embedded Tomcat 8!";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/page", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getPage() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("welcome");
        mav.addObject("firstname", "Amit");
        mav.addObject("lastname", "Shah");
        return mav;
    }

}
```

getting 404 with following details when i hit http://localhost:8080/app/page

error: message /WEB-INF/jsp/welcome.jsp
description The requested resource is not available.
Tomacat

```
public class MyMvcApp {
    private static final int PORT = 8080;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ServletException, LifecycleException {
        String appBase = ".";
        Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat();
        tomcat.setBaseDir(createTempDir());
        tomcat.setPort(PORT);
        tomcat.getHost().setAppBase(appBase);
        tomcat.addWebapp("", appBase);
        tomcat.start();
        tomcat.getServer().await();
    }

    private static String createTempDir() {
        try {
            File tempDir = File.createTempFile("tomcat.", "." + PORT);
            tempDir.delete();
            tempDir.mkdir();
            tempDir.deleteOnExit();
            return tempDir.getAbsolutePath();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(
                    "Unable to create tempDir. java.io.tmpdir is set to " + System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"),
                    ex
            );
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot (the presence of `MyMvcApp` would indicate so).

Comment: no, there is only tomcat config details there, i just added MyMvcApp code,
I am using gradle to package jar and running MyMvcApp main method to trigger tomcat

Comment: If you build a jar you should manually include all the webapp stuff, as by default that won't be included, AFAIK.

Comment: then what only running main method(without jar), in that case it should work!, but it is not working same errror

Comment: I doubt. The current directory is pointing to the package, not `src/main`.

Comment: I also feel the same (with string it;s working and not with jsp file), that's why i have added folder structure photo, do you have any clue on that could help?

Comment: Because the controller is detected doesn't mean the JSP is part of that. The classes are loaded (because tey are part of the classpath). THe JSP aren't on the classpath NOR are they resolved through the classpath!.